# Why were Austrian forces ineffective during the war of 1787 against Ottomans?

Tags: war, ottoman-empire, austria

In the French Wikipedia [article](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Roger_de_Damas_d%27Antigny) about Roger de Damas d'Antigny, it is said that this French officer was not satisfied by Austrian armies in the war against Ottoman empire, so he joined the Russian armies against the same opponent.

If I read information about this war of Austrian forces, between 1787 and 1792, the Austrian forces did not achieve significant success against Ottoman forces. Why is that?
The source for that is wikipedia, that says:

- "[the Austrian emperor] was a poor strategist"
- "The Ottoman raided the Austrian empperor"
- "Austrian forces suffer losses and did not capture Ottoman territory"

Comment: @MarkC.Wallace Thank you for the comment, I added info

Comment: The Wikipedia articles [Austro-Turkish War (1788–1791)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Austro-Turkish_War_(1788%E2%80%931791)) and [Imperial and Royal Army during the Napoleonic Wars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Imperial_and_Royal_Army_during_the_Napoleonic_Wars#Tactics) seem to cover much of this (some untrained men, 'incoherent' training, lack of finance, multinational army etc.). Also, the Austrians did have more success after a poor start. Perhaps you can edit if you think there is something missing here?

Comment: @LarsBosteen Thank you for the link
I edited about the missing thing which would be why the chief left